# Запуск в таймере одного класса, функций из другого

Tags: qt

У меня есть классы MyServer и  MainWindow. Как запустить в таймере класса MainWindow функцию из класса MyServer

Таймер:

```
connect(tmrserver, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateServer()));
```

Класс :

```
  сlass MyServer : public QObject    
    {    
        Q_OBJECT    
    public:
        explicit MyServer(QObject *parent = 0); // конструктор    
    signals:    
    public slots:   
        void updateServer();
    };
```

слот:

```
void MyServer::updateServer()
{
    MyServer serv;   
}
```

Пишет ошибки:

QObject::connect: No such slot MainWindow::updateServer()
QObject::connect:  (receiver name: 'MainWindow')

Код класса MyServer проверил отдельно, работает.

Comment: Он же пишет, что думает, что ваш солт в классе MainWindow. Не пробовали явно указать из какого класса слот?

Comment: Можете пример привести?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы рекомендовал писать так:

```
connect(tmrserver, &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyServer::updateServer);
```

И я проверил бы, а что за класс `this` у вас. Потому что компилятору кажется, что он скорее MainWindow, чем MyServer. А вам надо подключить к экземпляру класса MyServer, созданному в MainWindow.

Почему писать именно так, а не пользоваться SIGNAL: один раз тоже писал коннекты через `SIGNAL`. Проблема в том, что компилятор заранее считает, что это соответствие сигнал-слот правильное. А я переписал свой код так, чтобы сигнал 1 вызывал слот 2, а слот 2 уже слот 3. Так же через сигналы передавались некоторые данные. Изначально же было, что слот 1 вызывал сразу слот 3. Коннекты поменять конечно забыл. И получилось, что в слот 3 приходят данные от 1, причем совсем другого типа, программа не работает (Программа собирается, запускается, но работает некорректно). Идея в том, что SIGNAL как бы по умолчанию считает, что вы правы, т.е. это как явное преобразование типов. А, как я предложил, если типы переданных\ожидаемых данных не совпадут, оно будет ругаться на этапе компиляции. Вроде бы так.

Comment: Заработало так: `server = new MyServer();
       connect(tmrserver, SIGNAL(timeout()), server, SLOT(updateServer()));`

Comment: Отлично! Можете попробовать использовать предложенный мной синтаксис, для интереса, и как, возможно, немного более надёжный! Но главное что заработало!)

Comment: Добавлю, что в QtCreator можно автоматически переделать`connect` из старого синтаксиса в новый если встать курсором в любое место строки с `connect` и нажать alt+enter